# C++ ListControl - Icon position

Tags: c++, mfc, position, icons, listcontrol

When I use the "SetIconSpacing" command, the first icon isn't placed where it should be - any ideas why? (When I don't use SetIconSpacing they are depicted evenly)

Code:

```
VZ_Liste.SetIconSpacing(CSize (100,100)); 
verkehrs_icons.Create(64,64,ILC_COLOR32,29,0); 
CString strItem = _T("");
for (int i = 0; i<29; i++) 
{
  verkehrs_icons.Add(AfxGetApp()->LoadIcon(IDI_ICON1 + i)); 
  VZ_Liste.InsertItem(i, strItem, i);
}
VZ_Liste.SetImageList(&verkehrs_icons, LVSIL_NORMAL);
```

The current wrong behaviour:

[image: look at the first item]

Comment: What happens if you assign some text to `strItem`? `CString strItem = _T("not empty");`

Comment: One more thing: move the `SetImageList` before loop. You are setting the items' images before setting the image list.

Comment: if I assign the text it writes "not empty" beneath every icon

Comment: moving setimagelist before the loop was the solution! the only thing is, that the background of the icons is now black - any ideas why?

Comment: nevermind, i found the problem - thanks a lot for your help! :)

Answer (score 1):

You are using the images indexes before setting the image list. The correct sequence is:

```
VZ_Liste.SetImageList(&verkehrs_icons, LVSIL_NORMAL); // FIRST!
for (int i = 0; i<29; i++) 
{
  verkehrs_icons.Add(AfxGetApp()->LoadIcon(IDI_ICON1 + i)); 
  VZ_Liste.InsertItem(i, strItem, i);
}
```